# OAuth2 - handle password change in Spring Security

Tags: java, spring, security, spring-security, oauth-2.0

I'm implementing OAuth2 for my REST Service (password grant type) with help of Spring security module. I' using postgreSQL as my Token Store. All works fine, but I need to add the possibility to change user password. If user change his password old token should be deleted/forgotten.

I implement this feature using JdbcTokenStore Spring service:

```
public void updatePassword(User user, String newPassword) {
    ...
    // Update password in database

    clearUserTokens(user.getUsername());
}

private void clearUserTokens(String userName) {
    Collection<OAuth2AccessToken> tokens = jdbcTokenStore.findTokensByUserName(userName);
    tokens.stream().forEach(jdbcTokenStore::removeAccessToken);
}
```

Is this approach correct? Is there any standard way of handling that kind of situations?

Comment: Why do you want to delete the old token? The token should still be valid.

Comment: Security reasons. I want the action of changing password to cause "user logout" from any other devices.